# Script at specified location: scripts/install_ngnix.sh run as user root failed with exit code 100

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am about to deploy an application on EC2 but it shows this error which I couldn't understand how to resolve. Please look into this and tell me what am I doing wrong.

**"Error occuring while deploying on aws AfterInstall event:** Script at specified location: /scripts/install_ngnix.sh run as user root failed with exit code 100 **"**

Here's the appspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: var/www/html
    overwrite: true
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE

hooks:
AfterInstall: 
   - location: /scripts/install_ngnix.sh
     timeout: 300
     runas: root
ApplicationStart: 
   - location: /scripts/start_ngnix.sh
     timeout: 300
     runas: root
```

Here's the install_ngnix.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ngnix
```

Here's the start_ngnix.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service ngnix start
```

Comment: Don't post code as images. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask